# Parsing XML with special chars using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The GET service I try to parse using `ElementTree`, and whose content I don't control, contains a non-UTF8 special character:

```
respXML = response.content.decode("utf-8")

respRoot = ET.fromstring(respXML)
```

The second line throws

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character number: line 3591, column 39

How can I make sure that the XML gets parsed regardless of the character set, which I can later run a replacement against if I find illegal characters? For example, is there an encoding which includes everything? I understand I can do a search and replace of the input XML string but I would prefer to parse it first because my parsing converts it into a data structure which is more easily searchable.

The special character in question is `&#25;` but I would like to be able to ingest any character. The whole tag is `<literal>Alzheimer&#25;s disease</literal>`.

Comment: What is in line 3591?

Comment: I just edited the question, see the last sentence

Comment: Its not the encoding... its the `&#25;` unicode entity reference that's the problem. I'm not sure how to add external entities to ElementTree.

Comment: A simple example is `ET.fromstring("<a>&#25;</a>")`

Comment: I'm just trying to get past this hurdle in my parsing.

Comment: Entities of the form `&xdddd;` (where d is a decimal digit) decode to unicode and that one is for the "End of Medium" character which isn't valid xml. The only thing I can think of is replacing it with `&apos;` before passing it to ET.

Comment: i was thinking the same, which is unfortunately less than elegant

Comment: It looks like a bug in whatever generates the xml ... some hacking required.

Comment: it's the input in the DB where this data resides that doesn't get checked before persisting...

Comment: A good argument for scrubbing before it is inserted! This could be some sort of an encoding mismatch such as an mbcs being posted to an assumed utf-8 entry.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help from @tdelaney, I was able to get past this hurdle by scrubbing the input XML as a string:

```
respXML = response.content.decode("utf-8")

scrubbedXML = re.sub('&.+[0-9]+;', '', respXML)

respRoot = ET.fromstring(scrubbedXML)
```

Comment: eh? this isn't "getting past" the problem, this is deleting it. You simply removing the the special characters here.